# Extracting Content Within Multiple Span Tags in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract string content from and within multiple span tags. A snap shot of the HTML page is:

```
<div class="secondary-attributes">
    <span class="neighborhood-str-list">
        Southeast
    </span>
    <address>
        1234 Python Blvd S<br>Somewhere, NV 98765
    </address>
    <span class="biz-phone">
        (555) 123-4567
    </span>
</div>
```

Specifically, I'm trying to extract the phone number, nestled in between the `<span class="biz-phone></span>` tags. I attempted to do so with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

phone_number_results = [phone_numbers for phone_numbers in soup.find_all('span','biz-phone')]
```

The code compiled without any syntax errors, but it didn't quite give me the result I was hoping for:

```
['<span class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 476-5050\n    </span>', '<span class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 253-7296\n    </span>', '<
span class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 385-7912\n    </span>', '<span class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 776-7061\n    </span>', '<spa
n class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 221-7296\n    </span>', '<span class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 252-7296\n    </span>', '<span c
lass="biz-phone">\n        (702) 659-9101\n    </span>', '<span class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 355-9445\n    </span>', '<span clas
s="biz-phone">\n        (702) 396-3333\n    </span>', '<span class="biz-phone">\n        (702) 643-9851\n    </span>', '<span class="

biz-phone">\n        (702) 222-1441\n    </span>']
```

My question has two parts:

1. Why are the `span` tags appearing when I run the program?
2. How do I get rid of them? I could just do string editing, but I feel like I wouldn't be taking full advantage of the BeautifulSoup package. Is there a more elegant way?

NOTE: there are more snippets of HTML code like the one shown above throughout the page; there are more instances of the `<span class="biz-phone"> (555) 123-4567 </span>` code (i.e., more phone numbers) that need to be extracted, hence why I was thinking of using `find_all()`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `phone_numbers.text` or even `phone_numbers.text.strip()`

Comment: Thank you @furas, that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#find-all) returns a list of tags (`bs4.element.Tag`), not strings.
2. As @furas points out, you want to access the `text` property on each of the tags to extract the text within the tag:

   `phone_number_results = [phone_numbers.text.strip()
        for phone_numbers in soup.find_all('span', 'biz-phone')]`

(you may also want to call `strip()` on top of that)

Comment: Thank you, the `.text` did the trick! I wasn't aware of that property- I tried a few others (i.e., `.contents`) but that didn't seem to help. Your solution worked, though.